# How to have an accumulator for a signal in PyGObject?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygobject

I have a class which inherits from GObject. I need to emit a signal and stop when I receive a non-None result from any callback.

Something like this..

```
    class A(GObject.Object):
     __gsignals__ = {'get_my_object':(GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, subClassGObject, (int,))}

     def get_the_object(self):
      my_obj = self.emit('get_my_object')
```

Among the callbacks which ever returns the first non-None result that should be stored in my_obj, I don't know if this has to do with some kind of an 'accumulator' function. How do I get this done in pygtk?

Comment: Didn't get what is your question. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `@GObject.Signal` decorator, you can pass it an `accumulator` parameter. Documentation is here: https://github.com/GNOME/pygobject/blob/b2529624b3925adbef2671025e08cbf747f162e8/gi/_signalhelper.py#L49

```
@GObject.Signal(accumulator=GObject.signal_accumulator_first_wins)
def my_signal(self):
    return None
```